# MATLAB: What is the fastest csv read operation?

Tags: matlab, csv

There is csvread, dlmread, xlsread, and more ways to read a generic csv file (with multiple data types eg. strings and numbers).

I am reading a file with over 1 million data pairs, and another file with 40 million, and these take a long time to execute a xlsread.

What's the fastest operation to grab generic data?

Comment: I know that dlmread is meant for numeric data, but you can just start a csv file dlmread from an index that starts at numberic data in my application.

Comment: Have you tried just running all of them on a subset of your data and seeing which one works best? It is probably very system dependent.

Comment: I'm guessing straight call to fscanf

Comment: @raj I recommend to compare the options you know yourself and add the details to the question, then ask for possible improvements.

Comment: So I tried running a few things, but before I could proceed I realized that excel has a length cap (~1million points in my instance) and I have 5 million data points for four channels each...